# Reassigning a React Components prop value using let

Tags: reactjs

I understand that a components prop value cannot be reassigned, but what if you destructure props using `let` and then reassign their value? I don't see any negative side effect when using this approach.

Comment: Why? That's not going to rerender your component if that's what you're after. In any case, to prevent shadowing the prop and confusion, just redefine a new variable.

Comment: if you want to do some logic based on the prop that is being passed:

`let { id, pic } = props

if(id === 500) {
  id = 'megaman'
}
`

Comment: Just define a new variable, like `normalizedId` or something? Semantically they are also different because you're "processing" the ID in some way